# How to write custom filter in angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to add some filter to display the dependent question based on some trigger.

here is the fiddle URL

http://jsfiddle.net/gwt3Q/

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive("textquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '<label>{{question.displayText}}<br/><input name="{{question.qstnNo}}" type="text"/></label>',
        scope : { question: '=textquestion' }
    };
})
.directive("radioquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '{{question.displayText}}<br/><label ng-repeat="resp in question.demographicResponses"><input  name="{{question.qstnNo}}" type="radio" value="{{resp.respNo}}" /> {{resp.possibleResponse}} </label> ',
        scope : { question: '=radioquestion' }
    };
})
.directive("multiquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '{{question.displayText}}<br/><label ng-repeat="resp in question.demographicResponses"><input  name="{{question.qstnNo}}" type="checkbox" value="{{resp.respNo}}" /> {{resp.possibleResponse}} </label>',
        scope : { question: '=multiquestion' }
    };
})
.directive("selectquestion", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '{{question.displayText}}<br/><label> <select name="{{question.qstnNo}}"><option ng-repeat="resp in question.demographicResponses" value="{{resp.respNo}}"> {{resp.possibleResponse}}</option></select></label>',
        scope : { question: '=selectquestion' }
    };
})
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.questions = [
   {
      "seqNo":0,
      "qstnNo":34,
      "responseType":"F",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"If you have been provided with a state ID enter it here",
      "demographicResponses":[

      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":2,
      "qstnNo":2,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"What is your ethnicity?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Non-Hispanic",
            "seqNo":2,
            "respNo":201
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Hispanic",
            "seqNo":2,
            "respNo":202
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"I prefer not to respond",
            "seqNo":2,
            "respNo":203
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[
         {
            "dependentQstnNo":3,
            "triggerRespNo":202,
            "triggerArrayElement":"[202,3]"
         }
      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":3,
      "qstnNo":3,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"What is your Hispanic origin?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Mexican, Mexican, or Chicano",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":301
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Puerto Rican or Puerto Rican American",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":302
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Cuban or Cuban American",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":303
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Other",
            "seqNo":3,
            "respNo":304
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":true,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":4,
      "qstnNo":4,
      "responseType":"M",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"What is your race? Select all that apply.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"American Indian or Alaskan Native",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":401
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Asian",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":402
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Black or African American",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":403
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":404
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"White",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":405
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Other",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":406
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"I prefer not to respond",
            "seqNo":4,
            "respNo":407
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":5,
      "qstnNo":5,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":true,
      "displayText":"Do you communicate better (or as well) in English than in any other language?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Yes",
            "seqNo":5,
            "respNo":501
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"No",
            "seqNo":5,
            "respNo":502
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":6,
      "qstnNo":6,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"Which of the following best describes your current employment status?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Employed part-time (29 or fewer hours per week)",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":601
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Employed full-time",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":602
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Unemployed (seeking employment)",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":603
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Not in the labor force (homemaker, family caregiver, student, retired )",
            "seqNo":6,
            "respNo":604
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":7,
      "qstnNo":7,
      "responseType":"S",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"What was the last grade of school that you completed?",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"5th grade or lower",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":701
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"6th grade",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":702
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"7th grade",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":703
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"8th grade",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":704
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"9th grade (high school freshman)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":705
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"10th grade (high school sophomore)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":706
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"11th grade (high school junior)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":707
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"12th grade (high school senior)",
            "seqNo":7,
            "respNo":708
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":8,
      "qstnNo":8,
      "responseType":"F",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"What was the name of last K-12 school you attended?",
      "demographicResponses":[

      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":9,
      "qstnNo":9,
      "responseType":"F",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"City of last K-12 school attended",
      "demographicResponses":[

      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },

         {
            "possibleResponse":"Don't Know",
            "seqNo":13,
            "respNo":1308
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":14,
      "qstnNo":14,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"Please indicate the highest level of education completed by your <u>father</u>.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Grade school or less",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1401
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Some high school",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1402
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"High school",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1403
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Some college/university",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1404
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Associate degree",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1405
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Bachelor's degree",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1406
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Some graduate or professional school or a graduate or professional degree",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1407
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Don't Know",
            "seqNo":14,
            "respNo":1408
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":15,
      "qstnNo":15,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"What is your primary reason for taking the HiSET? Select the <strong>one</strong> which best applies.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Enroll in technical or trade program",
            "seqNo":15,
            "respNo":1501
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Enter a 2 year college",
            "seqNo":15,
            "respNo":1502
         },











   {
      "seqNo":20,
      "qstnNo":20,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"With 1 being \"No difference\" and 6 being a \"Significant difference\" indicate the extent to which <strong>financial difficulties</strong> have made a difference in your life over the last 12 months.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"1 - No difference",
            "seqNo":20,
            "respNo":2001
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"2",
            "seqNo":20,
            "respNo":2002
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"3",
            "seqNo":20,
            "respNo":2003
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"4",
            "seqNo":20,
            "respNo":2004
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"5",
            "seqNo":20,
            "respNo":2005
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"6 - Significant difference",
            "seqNo":20,
            "respNo":2006
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":21,
      "qstnNo":21,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"With 1 being \"No difference\" and 6 being a \"Significant difference\" indicate the extent to which <strong>legal issues</strong> have made a difference in your life over the last 12 months.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"1 - No difference",
            "seqNo":21,
            "respNo":2101
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"2",
            "seqNo":21,
            "respNo":2102
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"3",
            "seqNo":21,
            "respNo":2103
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"4",
            "seqNo":21,
            "respNo":2104
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"5",
            "seqNo":21,
            "respNo":2105
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"6 - Significant difference",
            "seqNo":21,
            "respNo":2106
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":22,
      "qstnNo":22,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"With 1 being \"No difference\" and 6 being a \"Significant difference\" indicate the extent to which <strong>family obligations</strong> have made a difference in your life over the last 12 months.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"1 - No difference",
            "seqNo":22,
            "respNo":2201
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"2",
            "seqNo":22,
            "respNo":2202
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"3",
            "seqNo":22,
            "respNo":2203
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"4",
            "seqNo":22,
            "respNo":2204
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"5",
            "seqNo":22,
            "respNo":2205
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"6 - Significant difference",
            "seqNo":22,
            "respNo":2206
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":23,
      "qstnNo":23,
      "responseType":"R",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"With 1 being \"No difference\" and 6 being a \"Significant difference\" indicate the extent to which <strong>issues with your health</strong> have made a difference in your life over the last 12 months.",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"1 - No difference",
            "seqNo":23,
            "respNo":2301
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"2",
            "seqNo":23,
            "respNo":2302
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"3",
            "seqNo":23,
            "respNo":2303
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"4",
            "seqNo":23,
            "respNo":2304
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"5",
            "seqNo":23,
            "respNo":2305
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"6 - Significant difference",
            "seqNo":23,
            "respNo":2306
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":24,
      "qstnNo":24,
      "responseType":"S",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"Thinking about yourself: to what extent do you agree with the statement \"I tend to do more than what is expected of me.\"",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Strongly Disagree",
            "seqNo":24,
            "respNo":2401
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Disagree",
            "seqNo":24,
            "respNo":2402
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Slightly Disagree",
            "seqNo":24,
            "respNo":2403
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Slightly Agree",
            "seqNo":24,
            "respNo":2404
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Agree",
            "seqNo":24,
            "respNo":2405
         },

      ],


      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":28,
      "qstnNo":28,
      "responseType":"S",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"Thinking about yourself: to what extent do you agree with the statement \"I tend to give up easily.\"",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Strongly Disagree",
            "seqNo":28,
            "respNo":2801
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Disagree",
            "seqNo":28,
            "respNo":2802
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Slightly Disagree",
            "seqNo":28,
            "respNo":2803
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Slightly Agree",
            "seqNo":28,
            "respNo":2804
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Agree",
            "seqNo":28,
            "respNo":2805
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Strongly Agree",
            "seqNo":28,
            "respNo":2806
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },
   {
      "seqNo":29,
      "qstnNo":29,
      "responseType":"S",
      "responseRequired":false,
      "displayText":"Thinking about yourself: to what extent do you agree with the statement \"I work on tasks until everything is perfect.\"",
      "demographicResponses":[
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Strongly Disagree",
            "seqNo":29,
            "respNo":2901
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Disagree",
            "seqNo":29,
            "respNo":2902
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Slightly Disagree",
            "seqNo":29,
            "respNo":2903
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Slightly Agree",
            "seqNo":29,
            "respNo":2904
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Agree",
            "seqNo":29,
            "respNo":2905
         },
         {
            "possibleResponse":"Strongly Agree",
            "seqNo":29,
            "respNo":2906
         }
      ],
      "dependentQuestionVO":[

      ],
      "selectedResponseIds":null,
      "freeFormAnswer":null,
      "isdependent":false,
      "answered":false,
      "triggered":false
   },


];});
```

Now what I want is to display the dependent question which is question number 3 based on the triggerRespNo: 202

I need to write a filter to do that. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You didn't actually put in the link. also, it is better to provide a link and put your code inline. We need to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have posted the fiddle link where I am trying to work on it. I am doing like this  <li ng-repeat="question in questions | isdependent:false"  ng-class="{true: 'required'} [question.responseRequired == true]"> This is helping me to hide the dependent question but I cant show it based on the trigger response for a particular question

Comment: This isn't an answer, but some advice (And possibly the reason some people aren't answering). Creating super-generic forms like this might seem like the most clever way to solve this problem, but it will create a maintenance nightmare for you down the road. As each option in your configuration requires new and differing features, the code to support the generic form will snowball into something monsterous. You're probably better off creating a form that is more targeted, and only abstracting smaller generic pieces you might need to reuse.

Comment: Side note: If you really like writing JSON to create forms you should check out [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) .. I'm an Angular fan through and through, but it seems like this might fit your needs and your coding style.